# You are writing a fiction / fictional book?

Tags: word-usage, difference

> 1. You are writing a fiction book?
> 2. You are writing a fictional book?
> 3. I am reading a fiction book.
> 4. I am reading a fictional book.

Are fiction and fictional interchangeable in the above context?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. "fiction book", or "work of fiction" would be appropriate in this context, and can be [defined](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fiction) as:

> the type of book or story that is written about imaginary characters and events and not based on real people and facts

"Fictional book" would refer to a book [whose existence itself is imaginary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_book), used within a work of fiction.

Examples:

1. Are you writing a work of fiction?
2. I am reading fiction.

Comment: I agree but "I am reading a fiction book" doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks. **I am reading fiction.** It is not necessary to indicate if is a book/story/article?

Comment: Using the same syntax, can I replace fiction with other subjects like History, Science, Literature?